# Batch file append slash to the beginning to string variable

Tags: batch, batch-file

I have a variable containing a path like this

```
a\b\c
```

And I want to turn it into something like

```
/a\b\c
```

I tried like this

```
set SLASH=/
set HOME_MF=%SLASH%%HOME:\=/%
```

and a number of other ways, but the slash just doesn't appear

Comment: Maybe [delayed expansion trap](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30284028/3439404)?

Answer (score 1):

I did

```
C:\> set ABC=a\b\c
C:\> set DEF=/%ABC%
```

and

```
C:\> set SLASH=/
C:\> set GHI=%SLASH%%ABC:\=/%
```

on my Windows 7 system, and I got `%DEF%` = `/a\b\c` and `%GHI%` = `/a/b/c`. 
You might get more help if you describe your system, what you want to happen,
what you are doing, and what is happening. 
"the slash just doesn't appear" isn't very much to go on.